# I need to check when for loop finished

Tags: android, android-studio, for-loop, asynchronous, kotlin

finish function works before for loop finished.Most solutions are similar but my i variable is a String not Int which I use in for loop(I'm using kotlin).Thaks.

```
       ekle.setOnClickListener {
        mydots.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ekle.isClickable  = false
        sekilbutton.isClickable = false
        storage2()

for (i in imagelist){
    storageEkle(i)

}
        finish()



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
imagelist.forEach {
     storageEkle(it)
}.also {
     finish()
}
```

Comment: I think you're storageEkle function doesn't finish in time. You finish() runs at the end of the forEach but storageEkle is not done. Can you add more code?

Comment: I solved problem by just doing some changes in my storageEkle problem must be that : storageEkle function is asynchronous.Thank you :D